# robot location prediction step

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In the `robot_localisation` package, when the `use_control` param is set to *true* then the values from the `cmd_vel` topic are used for the state prediction. But what if its set *false*. How does the prediction setup work?

I looked at one of the questions posed where it is explained how the prediction step works [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/221837/robot_localization-ekf-internal-motion-model/).

> The transition function for x is `x_new = x_old + vx * t + 0.5 * a * t^2`

Normally this would mean the `vx` and `a`are obtained from the previous state and when the  `use_control` param is *true*, then these values are obtained from `cmd_vel` topic.

When I look at the documentation of `robot_localisation` package, it says

> Note: The presence and inclusion of linear acceleration data from an IMU will currently “override” the predicted linear acceleration value.

Which I'm not able to understand as the values from the IMU are used for the correction step and not prediction.

I know I'm assuming something wrong here, but could someone please explain to me how it works?

Thanks
Sriram

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257260/robot-location-prediction-step/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The prediction step uses the current state to generate a predicted state. If you have `use_control` set to *true* and do NOT have an IMU present, it will use the controls to set the state's acceleration values immediately prior to prediction. If you have `use_control` set to *true*, and you also have an IMU present and are fusing accelerations, the filter assumes that measurements of acceleration are more accurate than the controls, and will use those. The same logic occurs if you have `use_control` to *false* in that case, but there's nothing measuring linear acceleration.

Control commands do not affect velocity during prediction, only acceleration.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0